# nesting array of objects based on the key value in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays

this question is an extension of the answer provided in this [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/278429/simplify-a-function-which-performs-manipulation-of-data-in-javascript).

I am trying to extend the solution further level to the group by `ownerName`. But somewhere I made a mistake, couldn't able to get the correct output.

Below I have added my work-around tries.

```
const data = [{"ownerName":"Apple","mName":"Nikolai","aName":"Dhanush","cName":"Thor Odin","id":"Client 1","gName":"","gAmount":"","gls":2,"value":0.855,"date":"22/1/2022","income":"","rows":[{"ownerName":"","mName":"","aName":"","cName":"","id":"goal-1","gName":"Retirement1","gAmount":10000,"gls":1,"income":"60/40","date":"22/1/2022","value":0.99},{"ownerName":"","mName":"","aName":"","cName":"","id":"goal-2","gName":"Save For Child Education","gAmount":70000,"gls":1,"income":"55/45","date":"5/12/2023","value":0.72}]},{"ownerName":"Apple","mName":"Nikolai","aName":"Dhanush","cName":"Steve Rogers","id":"Client 2","gName":"Save for Investment","gAmount":67000,"gls":1,"value":0.7,"date":"22/1/2022","income":"60/40"},{"ownerName":"Apple","mName":"Nikolai","aName":"Dhanush","cName":"Wanda Vision","id":"Client 3","gls":0,"value":0.9,"date":"","income":""},{"ownerName":"Apple","mName":"Nikolai","aName":"Dhanush","cName":"Tony Stark","id":"Client 4","gName":"","gAmount":"","gls":2,"value":0.29,"date":"27/10/2019","income":"","rows":[{"ownerName":"","mName":"","aName":"","cName":"","id":"goal-4","gName":"Education Loan","gAmount":500,"gls":1,"income":"60/40","date":"27/10/2019","value":0.29},{"ownerName":"","mName":"","aName":"","cName":"","id":"goal-5","gName":"House Loan","gAmount":23000,"gls":1,"income":"30/70","date":"16/6/2022","value":0.29}]},{"ownerName":"Apple","mName":"Nikolai","aName":"Joe","cName":"Hack Eye","id":"Client 5","gName":"Save For World Tour","gAmount":400000,"gls":1,"value":0.74,"date":"","income":"60/40"},{"ownerName":"Apple","mName":"Nikolai","aName":"Joe","cName":"Nick Fury","id":"Client 6","gName":"","gAmount":"","gls":2,"value":0.44499999999999995,"date":"9/3/2022","income":"","rows":[{"ownerName":"","mName":"","aName":"","cName":"","id":"goal-7","gName":"To Build A Workspace","gAmount":42340,"gls":1,"income":"60/40","date":"9/3/2022","value":0.6},{"ownerName":"","mName":"","aName":"","cName":"","id":"goal-8","gName":"Cloud Examination","gAmount":8730,"gls":1,"income":"30/70","date":"9/11/2021","value":0.29}]},{"ownerName":"Apple","mName":"Nikolai","aName":"Joe","cName":"Star Lord","id":"Client 7","gName":"Save For Child Education","gAmount":400000,"gls":1,"value":0.93,"date":"","income":"55/45"},{"ownerName":"Apple","mName":"Rohan","aName":"Pal","cName":"Thanos","id":"Client 8","gName":"","gAmount":"","gls":3,"value":0.29,"date":"2/11/2019","income":"","rows":[{"ownerName":"","mName":"","aName":"","cName":"","id":"goal-10","gName":"Relocation Expense Goal","gAmount":400000,"gls":1,"income":"22/78","date":"2/11/2019","value":0.29},{"ownerName":"","mName":"","aName":"","cName":"","id":"goal-11","gName":"Save for to buy bike","gAmount":400000,"gls":1,"income":"50/50","date":"1/1/2020","value":0.29},{"ownerName":"","mName":"","aName":"","cName":"","id":"goal-12","gName":"Save For Education","gAmount":400000,"gls":1,"income":"65/35","date":"9/5/2022","value":0.29}]},{"ownerName":"Apple","mName":"Rohan","aName":"Pal","cName":"Ego","id":"Client 9","gName":"Save For Education","gAmount":400000,"gls":1,"value":0.72,"date":"","income":"65/35"},{"ownerName":"Apple","mName":"Rohan","aName":"Pal","cName":"Bruce Banner","id":"Client 10","gName":"","gAmount":"","gls":2,"value":0.975,"date":"9/10/2018","income":"","rows":[{"ownerName":"","mName":"","aName":"","cName":"","id":"goal-14","gName":"Car Loan","gAmount":23000,"gls":1,"income":"60/40","date":"9/10/2018","value":0.99},{"mName":"","aName":"","cName":"","id":"goal-15","gName":"Bike Loan","gAmount":4600,"gls":1,"income":"30/70","date":"9/11/2021","value":0.96}]}]

const
nodOrder = 
  { ownerName:'',mName: '',  aName: '', cName: '', id: ''
  , gName: ''   ,  gAmount: '',  gls: '',      value: ''
  , date: '', income: ''
  } 
, levels = 
  { ownerName:   { arr: null, val: '' },
    mName: { arr: null, val: '' }
  , aName: { arr: null, val: '' }
  , cName:  { arr: null }
  }
, ResultData = []
;
data.forEach( ({ ownerName, mName, aName, ...otherProps }) => 
{
let
  row_0 = Object.assign({}, nodOrder, { ownerName })
, row_1 = Object.assign({}, nodOrder, { mName })
, row_2 = Object.assign({}, nodOrder, { aName })
, row_3 = Object.assign({}, nodOrder, otherProps )
  ;

if (levels.ownerName.val !== ownerName )
  {
  levels.ownerName.val = ownerName 
  levels.ownerName.arr = row_0.rows = []
  levels.mName.val = ''
  ResultData.push( row_0 )
  }

if (levels.mName.val !== mName )
  {
    levels.mName.val = mName 
    levels.mName.arr = row_1.rows = []
    levels.mName.val = ''
    levels.ownerName.arr.push( row_1 )
  }

if (levels.aName.val !== aName )
  {
  levels.aName.val = aName 
  levels.aName.arr = row_2.rows = []
  levels.mName.arr.push( row_2 )
  }

levels.cName.arr = (otherProps.rows) ? (row_3.rows = []) : null
levels.aName.arr.push( row_3 )

if (otherProps.rows) 
  {
  otherProps.rows.forEach( subRow => 
    {
    let sRow = Object.assign({}, nodOrder, subRow )
    levels.cName.arr.push( sRow )
    })
  }
})
console.log( JSON.stringify(ResultData ) )
```

This code is for the data table which shows the data based on the authorization levels.  Nesting will change based on the access level.

I am trying to group the data based on the `ownerName`. Data has been grouped under ownerName but further levels have not been grouped properly. Could you help me by fixing the mistake I am doing?

Comment: Can you post the output you want?

Comment: Meanwhile you shouldn't use `const` here as `levels` and `nodOrder` will be filled later.

Comment: @Dohab, I don't agree. `const` is appropriate because the intention is that no further **assignment** will be made to those variables. Mutation is irrelevant to the choice of `let` or `const`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the middle `if` your code resets the wrong property:

```
if (levels.managerName.val !== managerName )
  {
    levels.managerName.val = managerName; 
    levels.managerName.arr = row_1.subRows = [];
    // wrong: levels.managerName.val = ''
    // corrected:
    levels.advisorName.val = '';
    levels.ownerName.arr.push( row_1 );
  }
```

Side remarks:

- Make it a habit to separate your statements with a semi-colon. There is [automatic semi-colon insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) but you wouldn't be the first to fall into one of its traps. Better take control.
- It is common practice to reserve names with an initial capital for classes/constructors, so I would use `resultData` instead of `ResultData`

Comment: Sure, Thanks for the side remarks